# User is not deleting from LDAP Container

Tags: ldap

I have created a new user in .ldif file and it get appeared in the LDAP container also but later, when I deleted the user from .ldif file, that user is still appearing in LDAP container.

I'm using Apache Ds 1.5.5. I have deleted record from both .ldif files i.e "\Apache Directory Server\bin\filename.ldif" and "Apache Directory Server\instances\default\ldif\filename.ldif".

Comment: Why are you editing ldif files instead of using LDAP operations?

Answer (score 1):

`ldif` files are intended as input for tools like `ldapmodify` (see `man ldapmodify` and `man 5 ldif`). As such, they list usually *only* thos records you want to modify (add, change, delete). Objects not listed in the ldif file are not affectde (specifically, they do not get deleted by simply removing them from the ldif file).

Comment: Exactly, you have to do basically a change request to remove entries: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/utilities.html.  ldapdelete or ldapmodify with a changetype of delete. http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/263/delete-an-ldap-object-using-ldapmodify/